# How do I programmatically check if Infomatica target database table is being locked?

Tags: locking, etl, netezza, informatica-powercenter

Is there a way to check if a target table is being locked in your target database in Informatica PowerCenter for an ETL workflow load (L) process?  Or is it possible to get a list of all locked tables within all Informatica sessions?  If there is a way to check what tables are being locked directly in Netezza DBMS, that's fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying the system table `_T_PG_LOCKS` in Netezza will show which locks are currently active. You can do this in a mapping using a Lookup, SQL or Stored Procedure transformation, and apply logic based on the output.

There is also a Netezza utility called `nz_show_locks` that can be found in the 'bin' folder of an installation - this is handy if you need to retrieve locks at a Workflow level using a command task, if for example you only wanted to execute a Session task if there are no locks on the DB.